# WKWebView content jumping on load

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I've created a simple test app to reproduce my problem reliably and minimize the moving parts. It contains just a navigation controller and a view controller that I add a WKWebView to. I immediately tell that WKWebView to navigate to [www.google.ca](http://www.google.ca). Once the page has loaded, the content automatically jumps up underneath the header bar. This is reproducible consistently on various simulators/devices running iOS 8/9/9.1. Below is the code for my ViewController:

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.ca")!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
        webView.frame = view.bounds
    }
}
```

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 1):

put `webView.frame = view.bounds` before `view.addSubview(webView)`

Comment: putting it on `viewWillLoad()` gonna fix it

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions and neither of those fixes the problem. Well, not quite, viewWillLoad() doesn't appear to be a method on UIViewController but viewWillAppear() does so I tried that to no avail.

Comment: Also worth noting, this problem is website specific --> it happens on www.google.com but not on www.twitter.com.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced something similar while doing the following:

1. When a link is tapped on an existing WKWebView, in `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:`, I initialise a new view controller that controls a WKWebView and start loading content via URL request from a local web server running on the phone itself.
2. On `webView:didFinishNavigation:`, I push that view controller to a navigation controller.

What I was seeing: The content would load scrolled about 1/3 of the way, every time.

Things I tried that didn’t work: Asking the web view’s scroll view to scroll to top, setting the scroll position via JavaScript.

What did work: In Step 1, above, after initialising the view controller (which starts loading the URL request in the web view), I add the view controller’s view to my view (and send it to the back via `sendSubviewToBack:` so that it doesn’t show — I tried setting its `alpha` to zero and things went freaky).

That does the trick and the web content loads at the proper scroll position (top).

It sounds like this may be the same issue — so I hope that this might at least get you thinking of a workaround.